# Is there general formula for number of quotients greater than a given number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

For given $A,B \ge 2$, In division $A/B$ , if we consider

$Q_n=|\{ q: A=Bq+r ,  q \in \mathbb{N} , 2 \le B \le A-1 , q \ge n\}|$.

How to obtain $Q_n $ for large number?

For example:
$A=10$ and for $B =2,..., 9$ , $q=\{2,3,4\}$

$10=2*5$  So, $Q_5=1$

$10=2*4+2$ 
So, $Q_4=2$

$10=2*3+4=3*3+1$ So, $Q_3=4$

In other words, in division, how many quotients ( $q$ ) are equal or greater than  $n$ ? Is there any  formula?

Comment: If you are measuring the number of $q$'s, then the last condition $q=n$ implies that the number of such $q$'s can be at most 1, since you are looking at this quantity for one particular value of $n$.  Maybe you mean to be measuring something else?

Comment: @Alex , I'm looking for general formula, for example , how many quotients are greater than 25 when devidened is 10000?

Comment: But I'm talking about your $Q_n$ formula.  You ask, "how many quotients are *equal* to 25?"  Well, at most -- namely, 25 itself.

Comment: @Alex , your right, now I'll change it, thanks!

Comment: * at most *one*

Comment: Are you mixing up $100$ and $10$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson This is called team effort to help an OP (with a lot of rep!) become a better poster.  After that first inconsistency I went on to another question, and just now came back.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of ways to write $A=Bn+C$ with $B\in\Bbb N$ is $\lfloor A/B\rfloor$.

Now, you are excluding $B=1$; so in your case, with $A=10$, you would have

$Q_5-Q_6=\lfloor 10/5\rfloor-1=\lfloor 2\rfloor-1=1$.

$Q_4-Q_5=\lfloor 10/4\rfloor-1=\lfloor 2.5\rfloor-1=1$.

$Q_3-Q_4=\lfloor 10/3\rfloor-1=\lfloor 3.33\rfloor-1=2$.

Finally, you know that for $n>A/2=5$, you have $Q_n=\lfloor A/n\rfloor-1=1-1=0$, so to find your $Q_3$, you would sum starting with what value you are looking for, all the way up to $(Q_{A/2}-Q_{A/2-1})$, as follows:

$Q_3=(Q_3-Q_4)+(Q_4-Q_5)+(Q_5-Q_6)=2+1+1=4$

This would generalize in a straightforward way to higher $n$, using this exact procedure.

Comment: many thanks! ;-)

Comment: I'm glad I finally understood what you were asking for.  Because with all the typos in the original question, I couldn't understand what you needed.